# Unresolved import python VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, python-import, vscode-debugger

I can't understand why it doesn't resolve the imports.
[image]

Comment: How did you install `ask_sdk_core`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two things probably happened.

The first possibility is that you installed into a virtual environment and didn't select it as your environment in VS Code. If you open the Command Palette and run `Python: Select Interpreter` or click on the Python version in the status bar you can select the appropriate environment.

The second possibility is you ran `pip install ask_sdk_core` without be explicit about which installed copy to install Python for. That would mean you accidentally installed into a version of Python other than your Python 3.7.4 copy. You can fix this by using `python -m pip`, e.g. `<full path>/python3.7 -m pip install ask_sdk_core`. If this is what happened then I strongly recommend you use a virtual environment instead to make sure you don't install into your global copy of Python. It prevents breaking software that depends on your global Python and also keeps things clean and separated.